# Whats worng with the make file format

Tags: makefile

I wrote a makefile for my mini-project with gedit.
when I run "make", all *.o and executable created.
once I change one of my file (without make clean or make -B)
it's show it compile the chaneged file again and link all object again.
But the executable file works like nothing change.
(after "make -B" the executable file run ok)

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -Wall
OBJS = pawn.o knight.o bishop.o rook.o queen.o king.o board.o                           
movement.o game.o 

all: ex1

ex1: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o ex1


pawn.o: chess/tools/pawn.cpp chess/tools/tool.hpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c chess/tools/pawn.cpp

knight.o: chess/tools/knight.cpp chess/tools/tool.hpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c chess/tools/knight.cpp

bishop.o: chess/tools/bishop.cpp chess/tools/tool.hpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c chess/tools/bishop.cpp

rook.o: chess/tools/rook.cpp chess/tools/tool.hpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c chess/tools/rook.cpp

queen.o: chess/tools/queen.cpp chess/tools/tool.hpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c chess/tools/queen.cpp

king.o: chess/tools/king.cpp chess/tools/tool.hpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c chess/tools/king.cpp

board.o: chess/board.cpp chess/board.hpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c chess/board.cpp

movement.o: chess/movement.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c chess/movement.cpp

game.o: chess/game.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c chess/game.cpp 

clean:
    rm *.o
```

If there is another problem or suggestion with the design of the make file, I will be glad to hear about it.

Edit

1)The program is not print nothing to the screen.
2)The change is in king.cpp file (located in another folder) print Print Change to screen

```
  [av@ArchlinuxAvichai chess]$ ls
  chess  ex1  Makefile
  [av@ArchlinuxAvichai chess]$ ls chess
  board.cpp  board.hpp  game.cpp  movement.cpp  tools
  [av@ArchlinuxAvichai chess]$ ls chess/tools
  bishop.cpp  king.cpp  knight.cpp  pawn.cpp  queen.cpp  rook.cpp     tool.hpp

  [av@ArchlinuxAvichai chess]$ make
  g++ -Wall -c chess/tools/pawn.cpp
  g++ -Wall -c chess/tools/knight.cpp
  g++ -Wall -c chess/tools/bishop.cpp
  g++ -Wall -c chess/tools/rook.cpp
  g++ -Wall -c chess/tools/queen.cpp
  g++ -Wall -c chess/tools/king.cpp
  g++ -Wall -c chess/board.cpp
  g++ -Wall -c chess/movement.cpp
  g++ -Wall -c chess/game.cpp 
  g++ -Wall pawn.o knight.o bishop.o rook.o queen.o king.o board.o   movement.o game.o  -o ex1
  [av@ArchlinuxAvichai chess]$ ./ex1
  [av@ArchlinuxAvichai chess]$ *** AT this stage i change the file
  [av@ArchlinuxAvichai chess]$ 
  [av@ArchlinuxAvichai chess]$ make
  g++ -Wall -c chess/tools/king.cpp
  g++ -Wall pawn.o knight.o bishop.o rook.o queen.o king.o board.o  movement.o game.o  -o ex1
  [av@ArchlinuxAvichai chess]$ ./ex1
  [av@ArchlinuxAvichai chess]$ 
  [av@ArchlinuxAvichai chess]$ make -B
  g++ -Wall -c chess/tools/pawn.cpp
  g++ -Wall -c chess/tools/knight.cpp
  g++ -Wall -c chess/tools/bishop.cpp
  g++ -Wall -c chess/tools/rook.cpp
  g++ -Wall -c chess/tools/queen.cpp
  g++ -Wall -c chess/tools/king.cpp
  g++ -Wall -c chess/board.cpp
  g++ -Wall -c chess/movement.cpp
  g++ -Wall -c chess/game.cpp 
  g++ -Wall pawn.o knight.o bishop.o rook.o queen.o king.o board.o  movement.o game.o  -o ex1
  [av@ArchlinuxAvichai chess]$ ./ex1
  Print Change
  [av@ArchlinuxAvichai chess]$
```

Comment: Just to clarify, if you change a source file and run `make` the object file is being built, but the executable `ex1` is not relinked? Can you perhaps copy-paste the output of `make` into your question so we can see its output? How are you running your application? Do you change directories anytime while building or before running your program?

Comment: In absence of the `-o` flag to `$(CC)`, the object files are created next to the sources.  So let's say you change `chess/tools/king.cpp` and say `make`, then you'll get a new `chess/tools/king.o`.  But `ex1` wants to link against `king.o` and not `chess/tools/king.o`.  Which doesn't explain why `make -B` helps, though, so perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: Do you save the file with changes before compiling?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin yes, otherwise the make -B should not print the new version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following makefile:

```
CXX := g++
CXXFLAGS := -Wall
OBJS := pawn.o knight.o bishop.o rook.o queen.o king.o board.o movement.o game.o

COMPILE_CMD = ${CXX} -c -o $@ ${CXXFLAGS} -MD -MP $<
LINK_CMD = ${CXX} -o $@ ${LDFLAGS} $^

all: ex1

ex1: ${OBJS}
    ${LINK_CMD}

%.o : chess/tools/%.cpp
    ${COMPILE_CMD}

%.o : chess/%.cpp
    ${COMPILE_CMD}

-include $(OBJS:%.o=%.d)

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.d

.PHONY: clean all
```

Changes:

1. Use `${CXX}` for C++ code.
2. Auto-generate header dependencies.
3. Use pattern rules to avoid repetition.
4. Specify `.o` output files.
5. Mark targets `clean` and `all` as `.PHONY`.
6. Use `LDFLAGS` for linking.